# Make ASP.NET panel width the same as aspx page width

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, panel

I have the following aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="SectionPreview.aspx.vb" 
    Inherits="Management.SectionPreview" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style_1.css" />
    <link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="javascripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Addition Data Fields Section Preview</title>

    <style type="text/css">
    @import url('Style_1.css');
    .style1 {
       text-align: center;
    }
    .footerMenu {
      font: xx-small serif;
      color: #336699;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .CustomSize
    {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
             <asp:Label CssClass ="sectionTitle" ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Information required by your Department:"></asp:Label>
             <br />
             <asp:Panel CssClass ="CustomSize" ID="Panel_AdditionalData" runat="server" Width ="720px" Height="236px">
             </asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I pop this up as a modal window on a button click, that code executes as follows:

```
function showpage1() {
    var mydiv = $('#<%=poppage.ClientID%>');
    mydiv.dialog({
        autoOpen: false, modal: true, title: 'Data Field Preview', width: '75%',
        position: { my: 'top', at: 'top+150' },
        buttons:
        [
            {text: "Close", click: function() {$(this).dialog("close")}}
        ]

    });
    // Open the dialog
    mydiv.dialog('open');
}
```

I need to make the panel the same width and height as the page.  Everything I've attempted thus far has no effect. This page will be populated with controls that the user defines, IE; textboxes, drop down lists, etc. Yet I cannot get the Panel to expand to the width of the page. And, I'd like the panel to resize automatically when the page is resize by the user, assuming that's possible.

I haven't found any way to do that either. What am I doing wrong?

************* EDIT **************

This is the div that loads the target page into the div:

```
<div id="poppage" runat="server" style="display:none">
    <iframe src="SectionPreview.aspx" ></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab the window height (NOT the document height), and say 90% of that.

So, try this:

```
            var winHeight = $(window).height() * 0.9;
            function showpage1() {
                var mydiv = $('#poppage');
                mydiv.dialog({
                    autoOpen: false, modal: true, title: 'Data Field Preview',
                    width: '75%', height : winHeight,
                    position: { my: 'top', at: 'top+150' },
                    buttons:
                        [
                            { text: "Close", click: function () { $(this).dialog("close") } }
                        ]

                });
                // Open the dialog
                mydiv.dialog('open');
            }
```

You not need with style to set a width or height in the div that you pop as dialog. However, above should work for you. Tweak the 0.9 (for 90%) of the height, or use the full document height. I would think some padding should be left around the dialog, and you already have 75% width, and thus say 90% or 80% height should work quite well.

So, document.Height tends to get whatever part of the page height is, but window.Height gets the full height of the current browser window size.

I suspect with the given size, you probably want to remove your position settings, but regardless, the jQuery.UI dialog will wind up setting the height and width of the div, and overwrite the style settings you have set in the div.

## Edit: user is popping this form a different page

First up, for some reason the panel in question has TWO places in which the height and width are being set.

Next, the posted JavaScript is not correct, and shows no code that loads the other page.

So, in most cases, if you set the height of a div to 100%, it going to be 100% of the current section of that div, and not the whole page.

So, first, remove the TWO settings for height, and at least try to stick to ONE setting for the panel.

So, then on the page with the panel, then this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .CustomSize {
        height: 90vh;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: skyblue;
    }
</style>
```

So, in above, we don't just use 100% (which will be the current container on the page, but we use 100 of the viewport height. Or in above for this example 90vh (90% of viewport height)

Next up, the confusing part about multiple width and height settings existing for the panel (again, not clear why 2 settings exist).

So, removing the width and height from the Panel settings, and use the style sheet as you have.

Hence this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label CssClass="sectionTitle" ID="Label1" runat="server"
            Text="Information required by your Department:"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Panel
            ID="Panel_AdditionalData" runat="server"
            CssClass="CustomSize">
            <h3>tesat</h3>
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
</form>
```

When we run the above, we now see/have this:

[image]

Ok, so now we can move on to the 2nd page that pops the above.

Again, your posted code is wrong, and you STILL have to drop in a div on that page, and then specify that div, and THEN specify the other URL you want to load into that div on the current page. In fact, since the current page ALREADY has references to jQuery etc., then that other page should not have those references. I should also point out that as a result of doing this, that page you load will in most cases have to use JavaScript, and not code behind, since any post backs will re-direct to that loaded page. In other words, that loaded page quite much has to be full ajax without post-backs.

Ok, so on our second page, we have this markup:

```
    <div>
        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" 
            onclick="showpage1();return false;"/>

        <div id="mypopdiv">
        </div>

    </div>

    <script>

        function showpage1() {

            var winHeight = $(window).height() * 0.9;
            var myURL = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Test/MyPage1.aspx")%>';
            var mydiv = $('#mypopdiv');
            mydiv.dialog({
                autoOpen: false, modal: true,
                title: 'Data Field Preview',
                width: '75%',
                height: winHeight,
                position: { my: 'top', at: 'top+150' },
                buttons:
                    [
                        { text: "Close", click: function () { $(this).dialog("close") } }
                    ]

            });
            // Open the dialog
            mydiv.load(myURL);
            mydiv.dialog('open');
        }

    </script>
```

So, note how the jQuery.UI dialog used a .load command to get (pull) a copy of the other page into that div we placed on the current page. As noted, this means in general that code and post back's in that page can't occur. Hence code behind can't be used, and you write JavaScript and jQuery for the functions of that pulled in page to work correctly.

The result when we run above is this:

[image]

Last but not least?

Your close button code will not work, since that page is still be pulled into an existing div on the current page, and thus the JavaScript that the form calls will be in the current page, not the page you pulled.

Thus, your close button for the dialog should be based on the div that was popped, not using "this" as that now represents the current page.

Hence this:

```
buttons:
    [
        {
            text: "Close",
            click: function () { mydiv.dialog("close") }
        }
    ]
```

So, keep in mind that even the JavaScript for that pulled in page will run in the CURRENT page, and not from the target page.

## Edit2: Whopper big news is iframe being used

Ok, so the NEW information is that a iframe is being used, and thus it is a simple matter to set the size of the iframe. Obviously with a iframe, then we have to set the size of that iframe.

So, then this:

```
        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" 
            onclick="showpage1();return false;"/>

        <div id="mypopdiv" style="display:none">
            <iframe style="width:100%;height:100%" src="MyPage1.aspx" ></iframe>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script>

        function showpage1() {

            var winHeight = $(window).height() * 0.9;
            var myURL = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Test/MyPage1.aspx")%>';
            var mydiv = $('#mypopdiv');
            mydiv.dialog({
                autoOpen: false, modal: true,
                title: 'Data Field Preview',
                width: '75%',
                height: winHeight,
                position: { my: 'top', at: 'top+50' },
                buttons:
                    [
                        {
                            text: "Close",
                            click: function () { mydiv.dialog("close") }
                        }
                    ]

            });
            // Open the dialog
            mydiv.dialog('open');
        }

    </script>
```

So, by setting the iframe width and height to 100%, then it will fill out the pop div size.

The result is now this:

[image]

So, you are using a iframe, but that iframe has no width or height settings - it needs one.

Comment: How does this set the width/height of the panel on the aspx page?  That's what I need to do.

Comment: I had assumed the jQuery.UI dialog is relevant here?. OK, why does the panel have both a class with height/width and a height and width setting?

Comment: see my edit for some additional suggesting's here.

Comment: I edited my question to include the div that loads the target page on the parent.  Your suggestions have had zero effect on the panel, I've tried them all even though I suspected as much.  Your explanation makes zero sense to me, that may be due to my ignorance but that's the truth.  My close button works just fine, closes the dialog when clicked as expected.  When I added the style tag to the page being pulled in, it had zero effect.  No background color change, no size adjustment .... nothing .... no change to the page at all.

Comment: But my screen cap DOES show that the panel did render on the 2nd page, did it not? So, we need more markup.  And I assume you removed the 2 width settings for that panel (no reason for that to have been done). The posted markup shows the page loading the panel, and you can see that it has the blue background, and works as posted. Your new information shows a iframe - so that's 100% new information now.

Comment: see my edit. So the big new WHOPPER news is the iframe. So, you need to set the size of the iframe, and it will thus fill out whatever size the jQuery.UI dialog makes the div size.

Comment: Aaaannnnnddd we have a winner .... thanks for hanging in there with me.  I still don't understand why the style tag is not having any effect on the panel color, I used the exact same style tag code you supplied and yet the background color is still either white or transparent, not that I want to change the color, its just curious it doesn't change color.

Comment: Hum, perhaps I could dig further.  You have to set  background in the iframe source page, and anything much on the current page (that hosts the iframe) not going to effect anything. As my screen shot shows, the blue background does come through and as noted is on the actual page (iframe source).  So, any background settings will be in the source page, not the page with the iFrame. Not a big fan of iframe, but this example does mean you can ignore my suggesting that such a page can't have post-backs, since with iframe you can.

Comment: Ah, so it would seem that the iframe holds all control over the display of elements on the page being loaded, no?  If that is so, then would the placement of dynamic controls such as textboxes, labels, drop down lists also need to be controlled via the iframe or can I rely on the back end code to place those controls in the panel in the pageload event?  I won't be dealing with any postbacks in this particular instance as this is just a preview of the layout of controls defined by the user.

Comment: Whatever is in the iframe is what you have.  So, no, nothing in the hosting page going to really effect the layout (so, yes, the layout for iframe is controlled by whatever you have laid out in the iframe). Keep in mind that the iframe CAN call a parent javaScript routine. So, in theory, you can have a button in that iframe call a parent JS routine to close the iframe - but that's a different question. So, any kind of save button code in the iframe could do the save code (code behind), but it would then have to call a js routine in the parent to close the dialog.

Comment: Well, I'm soon going to find out what the issues are/will be.  Thanks again for the assistance.